# Android IncompatibleClassChangeError and Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-play-services

I got the following error after updating the app to play store, I didn't get the error but from the firebase crashlytics i found the following crash issue, so please let me know what i have to do or i require downgrade to older version now? or required to add following line?

```
      -keep class androidx.core.app.* { ; }
```

If I add the above line then is it best practice to do that? Is it secure?

My Error are following :

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass androidx.core.app.h of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity is declared final (declaration of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity' appears in /data/app/com.appname-oeUdZgLIV2eNSGZ5V1234==/base.apk)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztj.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


   Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Superclass androidx.core.app.g of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity is declared final (declaration of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity' appears in /data/app/com.appname-iX08rvGFm98xhqdpM01234==/base.apk)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztj.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Android Studio Version :

```
   2021.2.1 Patch 1
```

Google and Firebase gradle file version :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.33.4'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.33.4'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```

Firebase :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785592